# What is the integral division if $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} f(z)=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

In the chapter singularity I found that if $f$ is analytic on $B'(a;r)$ and if either $(i)$ $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} |z-a|^{\alpha}|f(z)| = 0$ or $(ii)$ $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} |z-a|^{\alpha} |f(z)|=\infty$ holds for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ then there is an integral division of the real line i.e. there exists an integer $h$ such that $(i)$ holds for all $\alpha >h$ and $(ii)$ holds for all $\alpha <h$ so that $(i) \iff (ii)$. If $f$ has a pole at $a$ of order $k$ then the integral division is precisely $k$. If $f$ has a removable singularity at $a$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} f(z)$ is a non-zero constant then clearly the integral division is $0$. Now  if $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} f(z) = 0$ then what would be the integral division? Is it still $0$ or some other? According to me the integral division should exist because for removable singularity $(i)$ always holds for $\alpha \geq 1$ and hence by the above discussion it is clear that $(ii)$ must hold which justifies the existence of such integral division. Is it not so?

Please help me in understanding this concept,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it depends on the order of zeroes of $f$ at $a$.

Comment: If $f$ has $k$ zeores at $a$ then the integral division is precisely $-k$ by what I have learned so far. Is it not so? Please verify it.

Comment: Did you get why everything follows from the Cauchy integral formula proving that holomorphic functions are analytic ? If $f$ is holomorphic on $0 < |z-a| <r$ and for some $k$, $\lim_{z \to a} |z-a|^k |f(z)|$ converges in $[0,\infty]$ then $(z-a)^2f(z)$ or $\frac{(z-a)^2}{f(z)}$ is holomorphic and hence analytic on $|z-a| < \epsilon$ so its behavior becomes obvious from its Taylor series.